# Combine - Delay publisher's send

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

What's the best way, to delay a moment when a publisher sends some data in Swift Combine? Let's assume following situation:

```
private var publisher: PassthroughSubject<Progress, Error>

// closure called every second:
startWithProgress() { [weak self] progress in
    self.publisher.send(.init(progress: progress))

    // How to call this 0.5 second after the above `send`:
    self.publisher.send(.init(progress: progress + 0.5))
}
```

I checked `Delay` API, but it seems I'd need to create another publisher to make use of it, which is suboptimal in my case. I also checked `throttle` and `debounce`, but those also don't allow me to send 2 updates one after another, with a given delay between them.

Comment: Based on the way you describe the ask, you could just wrap the second call in `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { ... }`

Comment: @NewDev I thought there's a more "Combine" way to do it. Something like: `self.publisher.delay(.milliseconds(500)).send(.init(progress: progress + 0.5))`. Based on the values sent by this `publisher`, I am updating some `@published` properties in a view model, which are then used by SwiftUI views. Should I assume that there's no better way to do it, rather than using GCD directly?

Comment: The point is that `self.publisher.send` is _not Combine_. This is _you_ talking, not Combine. And the way _you_ delay something by half a second is to do it half a second later, which is what `asyncAfter` does.

Comment: @matt I agree that it's me talking, not Combine, but `send` is `Subject`'s method which belongs to Combine framework. I thought there's some way to achieve what I need using Combine's APIs and concepts. 

To give you some more background - in my app I need to interact with some old APIs and I also need to interpolate results which I get from those APIs in callbacks and then update SwiftUI views based on those interpolated results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between delaying the act of sending the values - which you can do with `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter` - and creating a combine pipeline that delays upstream values.

You haven't specified any details about what you are actually trying to accomplish, so it's hard to give a definitive answer.

If I was to generalize, it looks like that you want a pipeline that for each upstream value it emits the value, then emits the value `+ 0.5` again, but delayed. This could be done like below, as an example:

```
let duplicateAndDelay = publisher
   .flatMap { [($0, 0), ($0 + 0.5, 0.5)].publisher } // duplicate
   .flatMap { (progress, delay) in 
      Just(progress)
         .delay(for: .seconds(delay), scheduler: RunLoop.main) // delay
   }
```

Then you can just `send` once:

```
startWithProgress() { [weak self] progress in
   self?.publisher.send(progress)
}
```

and return the `duplicateAndDelay` publisher, instead of the `publisher` publisher, to be subscribed to.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: To make it work on iOS13 I had to change `scheduler` in `delay` to: `.delay(for: .seconds(delay), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)`. TBH I am not sure why it doesn't work on iOS 13 with `RunLoop.main`.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from what you shared, I would not use Combine. [`DispatchQueue.asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300020-asyncafter) seems to be enough.

That being said if you must, you can use [`Publisher.delay(for:tolerance:scheduler:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/delay(for:tolerance:scheduler:options:)) :

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Progress, Error>()
subject.delay(for: .seconds(5), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .replaceError(with: .init())
    .sink { progress in
        self.publisher.send(.init(progress: progress + 0.5))
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

or even [`Publisher.publish(every:tolerance:on:in:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/3329589-publish)

```
Timer
    .publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .default)
    .autoconnect()
    .first()
    .sink { _ in
        self.publisher.send(.init(progress: progress + 0.5))
    }
```

or, if it makes sense in your case, have `progress` in a [`@Published`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) variable and use it to start a pipeline

Comment: I tried to use `delay` like in your example, but I get "Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'delay'. Adding `delay` before `send` also doesn't work, because it returns `Publishers.Delay<PassthroughSubject<Progress, Error>, RunLoop>`, on which `send` method can't be called.

Comment: my bad, I edited my answer, the trick is to call `replaceError(with:)`: `Publishers.ReplaceError.Failure = Never`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/replaceerror/failure

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, it might make more sense to use a timer. You will need to store cancellable in an instance variable so it doesn't disappear when the function returns.

```
var cancellable = self.publisher
    .delay(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: RunLoop.main )
    .sink(receiveCompletion:{ _ in
    // do something with the error or completion
}, receiveValue:{ [unowned self] progress in
        // you don't show any code that actually updates progress, without that this will just keep sending the initial value + 0.5.
        self.publisher.send(.init(progress: progress + 0.5))
    })
self.publisher.send(.init(progress: progress))
```

Comment: not testing is dangerous ;) `Referencing instance method 'sink(receiveValue:)' on 'Publisher' requires the types 'Error' and 'Never' be equivalent`

Comment: Nice, upvoted ;) `.sink(receiveCompletion:{ _ in` or it does not compile ;)

Comment: It seems like it's delaying the first value too, which is not what the OP wanted

Comment: OP call sent 2 times, I assume this is for the second time

Comment: if you only want to send it twice `Just` is the way to go, as in @NewDev's answer. I guess you wouldn't want to do something with the failure after a delay and instead just do nothing here if there's an error.